# 2 sites sharing one web application pool? when should this be used?

Tags: web-applications, iis-7

I just did a simple experiment. I created one web application pool in my local IIS, then I made 2 web sites point to the same app pool. Web sites are NOT virtual. and of course, they function OK locally.

When should we start using shared app pools? And under what circumstances should you ever share an app pool between 2 web sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do that for undemanding sites to save memory, separate app pool for small sites is in general memory waste.

Be aware that this way if your application pool recycles both application will be restarted, for example if you publish one site or just change web.config both web sites will be restarted (or more if you have more sites on app pool).

On shared hosting offten it's practice to put literally hundred of sites in one application pool :)

Comment: in shared hosting using plesk, I can modify the web.config for site, and that site will restart and first request will take about 15 seconds, but other sites are not affected, even though they share the same app pool

Answer (score 0):

It's not just websites that use app pools. Applications use app pools also. I know that I use the same app pool when I am using the same app server for both of them. If I have a different app server that I want to use, such as a different version, then I use a different app pool.

This is one common scenerio you'll see.