# .NET5 ASP.NET Core Web application and Application Pools

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

For .NET5 ASP.NET Core Web application deployed under Windows/IIS, can multiple websites be created that all use a common (the same) Application Pool?

And if "yes", what needs to be considered/configured to make this happen?

Finally, any links to where this is documented would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

[Something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255837) may help.

For example, we have the default website in IIS and we visit `localhost` we can see page like below:

[image]

And then we need to add another application to this website, we need to choose the default website and right click -> add application, then in the popup window, we set the name and choose the folder of the application.

[image]
[image]

Then we can see it.

[image]